# No se por qué al tratar de ejecutar el main.cpp me da este error

Tags: c++, visual-c++

/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccjZwxn9.o: en la función `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x20): referencia a`Grafo::inicializa()' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x2c): referencia a `std::allocator<char>::allocator()' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x43): referencia a`std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator const&)' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x56): referencia a `Grafo::insertarVertice(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x62): referencia a`std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator >::~basic_string()' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x6e): referencia a `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x7a): referencia a`std::allocator::allocator()' sin definir

> Este sería el main.cpp.

```
#include <iostream>
//#include <windows.h>
#include "Grafo.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    Grafo G;
    G.inicializa();
    int opcion;
    G.insertarVertice("Tierra");
    G.insertarVertice("Marte");
    G.insertarVertice("Venus");
    G.insertarVertice("Mercurio");
    G.insertarVertice("Jupiter");
    G.insertarVertice("Saturno");

    G.insertarArista(G.existeVertice("Tierra"), G.existeVertice("Venus"),500);//En millones de km.
    G.insertarArista(G.existeVertice("Tierra"), G.existeVertice("Mercurio"),200);
    G.insertarArista(G.existeVertice("Tierra"), G.existeVertice("Saturno"),600);
    G.insertarArista(G.existeVertice("Marte"), G.existeVertice("Jupiter"),100);
    G.insertarArista(G.existeVertice("Marte"), G.existeVertice("Venus"),500);
    G.insertarArista(G.existeVertice("Venus"), G.existeVertice("Saturno"),200);
    G.insertarArista(G.existeVertice("Mercurio"), G.existeVertice("Marte"),300);
    G.insertarArista(G.existeVertice("Mercurio"), G.existeVertice("Saturno"),800);
    G.insertarArista(G.existeVertice("Jupiter"), G.existeVertice("Tierra"),400);
    G.insertarArista(G.existeVertice("Jupiter"), G.existeVertice("Venus"),300);
    G.insertarArista(G.existeVertice("Saturno"), G.existeVertice("Jupiter"),300);
//    G.insertarArista(G.existeVertice("A"), G.existeVertice("B"),20);
    do{
        system("cls");
        cout<<"1. Ingresar Vertice"<<endl;
        cout<<"2. Ingresar Arista"<<endl;
        cout<<"3. Mostrar Lista de Adyacencia"<<endl;
        cout<<"4. Tamaño del Grafo"<<endl;
        cout<<"5. Eliminar Vertice"<<endl;
        cout<<"6. Eliminar Arista"<<endl;
        cout<<"7. Anular Grafo"<<endl;
        cout<<"8. Recorrido en anchura"<<endl;
        cout<<"9. Recorrido en profundidad"<<endl;
        cout<<"10. Primero en anchura"<<endl;
        cout<<"11. Primero en Profundidad"<<endl;
        cout<<"12. Primero el mejor"<<endl;//Pendiente
        cout<<"13. Salir"<<endl;
        cout<<endl<<"Elija una opcion: ";
        cin>>opcion;
        switch(opcion){
            case 1:{
                string nombre;
                system("cls");
                cout<<"Ingrese el nombre del Vertice: ";
                cin.ignore();
                getline(cin, nombre, '\n');
                G.insertarVertice(nombre);
                cin.get();
                cin.get();
                break;
            }
            default: { // caso de una opcion que no corresponda a las mostradas
                printf("Opcion inválida");
            }



        }
        getchar();


    }while (opcion != 13);
return 0;
}
```

> El Grafo.h

```
// #ifndef GRAFO_H
#define GRAFO_H
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <list> 
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

class Arista;


class Vertice {
    Vertice *siguiente;
    Arista *adyacente;
    string nombre;  //Ejemplo de Planetas, para matar dos pajaros en uno xD.
    friend class Grafo; //Para que pueda usar los atributos. 
};

class Arista {
    Arista *siguiete;
    Vertice *adyacente;
    int peso;  //La distancia entre los planetas.
    friend class Grafo;
};

class Grafo {
    Vertice *primerVertice;
    public:
        void inicializa();//Inicializar en null al primer vertice.
        bool vacio();   //Indica si está vacío el Grafo
        int tamano(); //Indicará el numero de vertices que tiene el grafo.
        Vertice *existeVertice (string nombre); //Con esta funcion obtenemos la direccion del vetice.
        void insertarArista(Vertice *inicio, Vertice *destino, int peso);//Insertamos una arista dandole el vertice inicial y el final
        void insertarVertice (string nombre); //Insertamos el Vertive nuevo
        void listaAdyacencia ();    //listas de los vertices
        void eliminarArista(Vertice *inicio, Vertice *destino);//Eliminar las conexiones entre vertices.
        void anularGrafo(); //Anula todas las conexiones del grafo y los elimina.
        void eliminarVertice(Vertice *verticeEliminar);//Se encarga de eliminar un vertice del grafo.
        void recorridoAnchura(Vertice *inicio);
        void recorridoProfundidad(Vertice *inicio);

};
```

> Y el GrafoDinamico.cpp, no lo envío completo porque es muy largo, pero se ve el encabezado, donde se llama al Grafo.h

```
#include "Grafo.h"

void Grafo::inicializa() {  //Función para inicializar el grafo.
    primerVertice = NULL;   //Se inicializa el primer elemento.
}

bool Grafo::vacio() { //Verifica que el Grafo no esté vacio.
    if (primerVertice == NULL) {//Si el grafo está vacia retorna verdadero
        return true;
    }else {//Si no está vacio retorna falso.
        return false;
    }
}

int Grafo::tamano() { //Calcular la cantidad de vertices del grafo.
    int contador;
    Vertice *aux; //Este auiliar se encarga de recorrer el grafo.
    aux = primerVertice;    //Se inicia el auxiliar en el primer vertice
    while (aux != NULL) {   //Cuando sea diferente al ultimo.
        contador ++;    //Aumneta el contador cada que encuentra un vertice
        aux = aux->siguiente; //Si no es el ultimo vertice 
    }
    return contador;
}
Vertice *Grafo::existeVertice(string nombre) { //Indica donde está el vertice
    Vertice *aux;   //Auxiliara para recorrer el grafo
    aux = primerVertice;    //Se inicia el auxiliar como el primer vertice
    while (aux != NULL) {   //Ciclo para recorrer el grafo hasta que encuentre el vertice.
        if (aux->nombre == nombre) //Si el auxiliar es igual al nombre del evrtice, lo retorna.
            return aux;
        aux = aux->siguiente;   //Si  no es el vertice pasa al siguiente.
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en tu **main.cpp** incluyes a **Grafo.h** y esta cabecera ***no tiene el método inicializa***, el método inicializa esta en **GrafoDinamico.cpp**, por eso te envia el error de que no esta definido ese método.

Comment: Eso era, muchas gracias por la ayuda.